# Calculate claim amount?

Tags: self-study

Let X be the random variable representing the claim amount for flooding damage from house insurance policies of bungalow type houses. Past claims show evidence that X is a normally distributed random variable with an average claim amount of μ = 21000 euro and a standard deviation of σ = 4000 euro.

e) An insurance company notes that for 2.5% of claims the claim amount is above K euro, calculate K.

I am lost is 2.5% is the z-score? How can you solve this?

Comment: Sigh.  Insurance claims are so not normally distributed.

Comment: This looks like a homework problem, you need to add the self-study tag.  It would help for you to explain your understanding of z-scores and describe why you think it is useful in this problem.

Comment: I have the self-study tag, please help me thanks

Comment: The z score would require a value for X  It would be (K -21000)/4000. The 2.5 % represents the percentile of the standard normal distribution.  From that you get Z and can then determine K..

Answer (score 1):

The information given in the problem tells you that

$$ \text{Claim Amount} \sim N(21000, 4000) $$

The second piece of information tells us that the number $K$ is unknown, but satisfies

$$ P(\text{Claim Amount} \geq K) = 0.025 $$

Or, in terms of the left tail

$$ P(\text{Claim Amount} < K) = 1 - 0.025 $$

The cumulative distribution function of the normal distribution with mean $21000$ and standard deviation $4000$ describes these probabilities.  I'll use the notation $\Phi_{21000, 4000}$, for this cumulative distribution function

$$ \Phi_{21000, 4000}(K) = 1 - 0.025 $$

To isolate $K$, we need to use the inverse function

$$ K = \Phi_{21000, 4000}^{-1}(1 - 0.025) $$

Now it's just using whatever software you are comfortable with to compute this quantity.  I'll use python

```
normal = norm(loc=21000, scale=4000)
normal.ppf(1 - 0.025)
```

This gives me the result $K \approx 28839$.

As a check

```
normal.cdf(28839)
```

Returns $\approx 0.975$.

Comment: It gave me as a wrong answer

Comment: What is the greek symbol never seen it. Can you solve it by hand?

Comment: That's a capital phi, which is usually used for a cumulative distribution function of the normal distribution.  I don't think there is a way to do this without a computer, or a calculator, or some tables containing values of the CDF of the normal distribution (which would be a very antiquated way to do things).

Comment: How do you do it on a calculator? As I have got new numbers and python is not working for me, I am not good at coding. Thank you for your reply

Comment: I suppose that depends on the calculator you are using.  There are probably calculators that have the functionality to do it exactly this way.